# How do I make $_POST act like $_GET for search queries?

Tags: php, mysql, html, search, post

Basically I have a search query, which works fine if I'm using it with $_GET, but I want to use $_POST for one of them (then return with json). However I'm unsure how to accomplish this so that the search will look at each word individually...

Here's my search query...

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT(auto), user_id, username, first_name, last_name, email, sex, active, ppic, time_zone, adult_filter, ((CASE WHEN `username` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `last_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS relevance
FROM users, network
WHERE `username` LIKE '%$search%' OR
  `last_name`LIKE '%$search%' 
  OR `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' 
ORDER BY relevance DESC, username LIMIT 5
```

So basically, all I need to do is make `$search = $_POST['search']` functional with this query... can anyone tell me how this is accomplished?

EDIT:
Looks like I can just use $.get... (which makes a lot of sense) rather than $.post (which is what I was used to) and get the same result. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, however I'm going to try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Depending on the source of your `$search` variable, your query may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for more info.

Comment: I escape it for security,function wash($str) {
 $str = @trim($str);
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $str = stripslashes($str);
 }
 return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$example = wash($_POST['example']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you **shouldn't** do this.

Now, the long answer ...

Why would you want to use `$_POST` for a read request in the first place? Let me introduce you to the concepts of  **safety** and **idempotence** in the context of HTTP.

The [HTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_toc.html) spec says:

> If the processing of a form is idempotent (i.e. it has no lasting
>   observable effect on the state of the world), then the form method
>   should be GET. Many database searches have no visible side-effects and
>   make ideal applications of query forms.

### A bit about HTTP GET

The HTTP verb `GET` was specifically created to retrieve a resource without any possibility of changing it. What I mean is that it's **safe**. It doesn’t cause any side effects. A `GET` request in your case should be used to *get* data from a database and display it. Existing HTML pages, images requests, database searches, etc. ... these are all safe requests that should be made with `GET`.

Meanwhile, **idempotent** means that executing the request 724 times will have the same effect as doing it once. An idempotent request might create something in a database the first time, but it won’t do it again or it will just return the reference to it the next time around.

The HTML spec continues ...

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

So, in summary, please understand that you **shouldn't** use `POST` to perform safe, read-only operations.

Comment: I'm not doing it for security reasons, I'm doing it so that I can use $.post and automatically retrieve the submissions (without page refresh). I have no clue how to do this (and assumed it wasn't possible) using $_GET.

Comment: Without editing the answer I'd like to add that if instead of making a `SELECT` query you make an `INSERT` or `DELETE` SQL query, you should then use POST. And **ALWAYS** escape your queries or more preferably use prepared statements to query the DB.

Comment: "Shouldn't" is a harsh term here since it doesn't consider how the user prefers to present their site. Supposing you want a clean url for some reason or another you can merrily use post to process and rewrite the url, then send it back to a new page both preventing a repost warning as well as cleaning your url for who knows why (I've had clients request this or I wouldn't bother mentioning it). You'd be using a uri segment in place of get but it doesn't really matter at that point. As for safe, you're in control of what you do with post or get data so safe is as safe as you make it.

Comment: @itdoell It has nothing to do with security. You're abusing HTTP. Nothing's going to stop you from doing it, but if you do you'll be the **Internet Explorer 6** of Ajax applications.

Comment: @KaiQing your comment precludes the possibility of generating clean URLs correctly using rewriting or other tools. `$_POST` should **NEVER** be used to create clean URLs. And no, *"shouldn't"* is probably too light. I should've gone with something closer to "never" or **"don't  do it or they'll ship you to Guantanamo Bay"** ...

Comment: ... i see, for ajax purposes. Well, you can specify method: "GET" in your $.ajax() params.

Comment: That's a little dramatic for the situation. Until php makes $_POST contextual then it's a moot point.

Comment: @KaiQing The point is ... there are standards for a reason. People, *especially* those who are just learning about creating internet sites and applications, should be encouraged to use them as much as possible. I, for one, prefer the internet of 2012 to the internet of 1996.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6804/discussion-between-kai-qing-and-rdlowrey)

Comment: @rdlowrey Thanks for your help. This is the first semi-complex site I've ever built so I'm really just learning as I go. I appreciate you clarifying why what I was doing would be bad.

Answer (score 3):

Use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) - It contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear, or I'm just not understanding $_REQUEST. I'm not sending the query two different ways, I'm only doing it with $_POST. I plan to use $.post to asynchronously return results. So (to the best of my knowledge) it needs to be done as $_POST. Am I wrong in this thinking?

Comment: @itdoell - What I understood (from your post) that you want to use request parameter value any how - GET or POST. You want to use $.post jquery method to pass data so I don't think that will be a problem. You may request using POST method via $.post and on other end receive request parameter using $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into mysql [match against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for relevance and matching on several columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(auto), user_id, username, first_name, last_name, email, sex, active, ppic, time_zone, adult_filter, ((CASE WHEN `username` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `last_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS relevance
FROM users, network WHERE MATCH (username, first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC, username LIMIT 5;
```

ADV's suggestion for $_REQUEST will work for capturing post and get.

However, you asked for relevance regarding each word in the search term. Match against can do this too, but you need to select it as a column...

```
SELECT MATCH (username, first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('$search') AS relevance, DISTINCT(auto), user_id, ...
```

Don't forget to look up match against in that link I provided though. If you're new to it you will need to know a couple things - like requiring myisam tables and full text index on the columns you intend to search.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just updated that search query last night, I had originally been using match except the whole "natural language" filter was throwing me off so I scrapped it for that version. I like yours better though. Much appreciated.